# Cannot execute spark task on remote EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I have Spark 2.3 running on an EC2 instance. All ports are open and I started spark with "start-master.sh" and "start-slave.sh ". I try to connect using Java with the following code:

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("myappname")
            .setMaster(System.getProperty("spark.master", "spark://<EC2 DNS>:7077"));
```

and it seems to connect, and I can see it in the web UI. However, when I try to actually execute something I get the following error message:

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

There should be plenty of resources available, both cores and memory for this job, and I think it's an issue where the driver (my local machine) and the worker (on EC2) are failing to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following:

Update my SparkConf in Java:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("myappname")
    .setMaster(System.getProperty("spark.master", "spark://<EC2 DNS>:7077"))
    .set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
    .set("spark.driver.port", String.valueOf(23584));
```

Then I ran this to make an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -R 23584:localhost:23584 ubuntu@<EC2 DNS>
```

You can use anything for the port, I selected 23584 randomly. I'm still having issues but this seems to have solved the error I was getting above.